# How to build node.js with --harmony flag on windows

Tags: windows, node.js

I would like to build 0.11.x version  of node.js on Windows from sources with enabled --harmony flag. Sometimes it's very useful like in testing.

How I can configure v8-options during the build process? I build using this command:

```
vcbuild.bat nosign release x64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - Install python
 - Install Visual Studio (Desktop Express is ok)
 - For MSI
 - Install WIX (3.8 is ok) https://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/115492
 - Install .NET 3.5
```

Within the folder with checked out node.js 0.11.x run:

```
- python configure --dest-cpu=x64 --v8-options=--harmony
- .\vcbuild.bat release nosign x64 noprojgen msi
- run msi package from Release folder
```